# ExifInterface doesn't update exif tags

Tags: android, image, exif

I'm trying to change exif tags with ExifInterface. I use setAttribute() and call saveAttributes(). The tag is saved temporarily, then next time the old value is still there and hasn't been updated................

Example:

```
ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(filePath);

String o1 = exifInterface.readAttribute(TAG_ORIENTATION); //o1 is "0"

exifInterface.setAttribute(TAG_ORIENTATION, "90");
exifInterface.saveAttributes();

String o2 = exifInterface.readAttribute(TAG_ORIENTATION); //o2 is "90"

// relaunch app, read attribute for same photo

String o3 = exifInterface.readAttribute(TAG_ORIENTATION); //o3 is "0" again, sould be "90"
```

Answer (score 8):

Just in case someone is looking for a pure android solution: original code is correct, but value of `TAG_ORIENTATION` attribute must be a value between 1 and 8, as explained in [this page](http://sylvana.net/jpegcrop/exif_orientation.html).

You must suppress the line with the call to `readAttribute()` method, this method doesn't exist in the ExifInterface class. Replace it with `exifInterface.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, defaultValue)` if you want to read the value before and after the modification.

Comment: I have managed to change the update exif tags, but yet my image isn't rotated. how come?

Comment: Hi i'm doing this `ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(file.getPath());
   
   int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);` then `switch(orientation)
   {
    case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
     
     exifInterface.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ""+ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90);
     
     exifInterface.saveAttributes();
     
     break;` but no luck!

Comment: @eternay do you have any idea why the exif data isn't written to image in my question?   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732781/how-to-write-exif-data-to-image-in-android

Answer (score 4):

Also make sure your app has the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Comment: Good catch. It was my problem. Saving file happens in native method so that it doesn't complain about missing permissions but requires one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use something like

```
exifInterface.setAttribute(TAG_ORIENTATION, ""+ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90);
```

instead

Comment: Hi, I've solved the issue by using [sanselan](http://code.google.com/p/sanselanandroid/). Works perfectly

Comment: I prefer eternay's solution. IMHO introducing a library for such a simple case is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```