# Is it possible to change image orientation changing exif attribute?

Tags: android, image

I'm stuck trying to rotate an image in my app. The image come from the camera and is saved in the devices external storage. I need to rotate the image and save his modification on the sd, with the help of `ExifInterface` class and without opening the image and charging it in memory (this would throw `OutOfMemoryException` due to the dimensions of the image). 
I'd like to know if it's possible to use the Exif solution to rotate the image and how to accomplish this task.
This is my first app so plz be patient and thx for any help ^^

edit: I've tried to change orientation attribute with `setAttribute(String tag, String value)` to change the orientation the image is visualized. But this is impossible because Orientation constants are int type. So I'd like to know if i did not understand the use of `setAttribute()`or if i'm simply using it in a wrong way.

Comment: I do not know what you consider "the Exif solution" to be. `ExifInterface` simply deals with EXIF tags; you cannot use `ExifInterface` to rotate an image.

Comment: I edited the question to be more specific

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExifInterface doesn't update exif tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186795/exifinterface-doesnt-update-exif-tags)

Comment: i apologize for the duplicate qeustion, i'll be more careful next time. Anyway, thx for the help.