# Rotate an ImageButton on orientation change

Tags: android, android-orientation, image-rotation, android-imagebutton

I have an image button that I want to rotate when the orientation of the device changes. How can I rotate the image with some animation or transition ?

Comment: [check this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19753912/set-image-orientation-using-exifinterface)

Comment: [RotateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html) ?

Comment: @vits that post refers to changing orientation of an image from gallery. My question is regarding an ImageButton that should adjust as the device changes orientation

Comment: then you can check for RotateAnimation

Answer (score 3):

try this code snippet.

**rotate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate

android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="0"
android:duration="2000" />

</set>
```

**rorate_anticlockwise.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="-360"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:repeatCount="0"
android:duration="2000" />
</set>
```

for checking orientation of the phone use this code

```
int orientation =this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
```

the complete code for **MainActivity.java** is

```
public class MainActivity  extends Activity{

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
ImageButton image_btn;

Animation ranim_clockwise, ranim_anticlockwise;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    image_btn= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    ranim_clockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate);
    ranim_anticlockwise = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.rotate_anticlock);
    int orientation =this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
    if(orientation==1){ // portrait mode
        image_btn.setAnimation(ranim_clockwise);
    }
    if(orientation==2){  //landscape mode
        image_btn.setAnimation(ranim_anticlockwise);
    }

}
```

}

hopefully it will help you.

Comment: After rotation the image button goes back to it's original position
I need the image button to remain in the new position

Comment: @Meeth i have edited my code having added anticlockwise rotation xml file and set it in different mode to rotate imagebutton.

Comment: I have used an Image Button for a Custom Camera app. My objective was to rotate the Image Button as the User rotates the device specific to potrait, landscape, reverse_potrait & reverse_landscape modes both in clockwise & anticlockwise direction.

Comment: @Meeth change the rotate.xml file according to your need and check orientation of phone and apply specific rotation on imagebutton.