# Changing the orientation of buttons, letting the activity to remain in only one orientation

Tags: android, button, camera, orientation, preview

Assuming that the current android's activity is set to:

```
 android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
```

Is there any way to change the orientation only for buttons? So that the other childs stay in the same orientation, as stated in android manifest.

What I'm asking is related with a streching camera preview. As long as the **android:screenOrientation** is set to some value like **landscape** or **portrait**, then the switching to different orientations doesn't really affect the camera preview, the ratio and size is perfect. But when it comes to just remove this **screenOrientation** part in order to make the buttons rotate with the phone, so that they follow changing orientation....the landscape preview gets stretched like x2.5 time, making the preview look bad.

Comment: Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all whom might look for the answer, concerning stated question, there are smart way to achieve this, just follow these topic above

[Rotate an ImageButton on orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677870/rotate-an-imagebutton-on-orientation-change)

[How to rotate views on orientation change without recreating layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34955879/how-to-rotate-views-on-orientation-change-without-recreating-layout/34970844#34970844)