# How to write exif data to image in Android?

Tags: java, android, exif, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to write a `User_Comment` and `TAG_GPS` to a captured image in an Android application using the exif interface, but for some reason the tags don't seem to be appended to the image when I view the image's details in the gallery.

It seems that maybe the tags are not being written to the captured image as the file path may be wrong. I think it could be because I've written the tags to an incorrect image path.

Does anyone know if their is a problem with the way I'm writing the tags to the image?

This is the code that saves the exif data following @Charlie's changes below:

```
private File getOutputPhotoFile() throws IOException {
          File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), getPackageName());
          if (!directory.exists()) {
            if (!directory.mkdirs()) {
              Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create storage directory.");
              return null;
            }
          }


          String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());

          File[] files = directory.listFiles();

          File exifVar =  new File(directory.getPath(), "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
          if(files.length!=0) {
              File newestFile = files[files.length-1];
              exifVar =  new File(directory.getPath() + File.separator + newestFile.getName());
          }

          String mString = "Generic Text..";     
          ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(exifVar.getAbsolutePath());
          exif.setAttribute("UserComment", mString);
          exif.saveAttributes();


          exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE,
            String.valueOf(latituteField.toString()));

          exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, 
            String.valueOf(longitudeField.toString()));

          exif.saveAttributes();

          return exifVar; 




    }
```

Comment: why are you calling exif.saveAttributes multiple times? I believe that creates a new image each time. Just wondering

Comment: Its possible, I haven't worked on this project in a while, I think the problem may have been that the data is being saved to a temp image called "exif" and is never written to the original image.

Answer (score 5):

You need first to copy the exif files located here [google exif](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/android-5.0.2_r1/gallerycommon/src/com/android/gallery3d/exif/) to your project, then use the following code :

```java
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface();
    exif.readExif(exifVar.getAbsolutePath());
    exif.setTagValue(ExifInterface.TAG_USER_COMMENT, mString);
    exif.forceRewriteExif(exifVar.getAbsolutePath()));
```

ExifInterface used here is the new one you've just added.

Comment: It'd be better if you can specify the data type and initialisation of variable "exifi"

Answer (score 2):

You're using `exifVar.toString()`. This returns just the filename, not the path to the image. As your app is probably not in the folder with pictures, you should use `exifVar.getAbsolutePath()`.

If you're not taking the picture at the same time you're running the program, the Path won't be right. Use this code instead:

```
File[] files = directory.listFiles();

if(files.length==0) {
    // No images available
    return;
}

File newestFile = files[files.length-1];

File exifVar =  new File(directory.getPath() + File.separator + newestFile.getName());
```

Off-Topic:

According to your huge import list:

```
import android.content.*;
```

imports

```
android.content.Context,
android.content.DialogInterface and
android.content.Intent
```

That makes your code quite a bit shorter. Just saying

Comment: the exif data still doesn't get added to the image details after the above changes, do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the write to sd permission (both static and dynamic),
Also for Android 10, you need to set this:
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"

to the manifest application